# Does Postgres have something similar to Oracle's Virtual Private Databases?

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql

As the title suggests, does anyone know if such a thing exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the Postgres [Veil](http://veil.projects.postgresql.org/curdocs/main.html) project does this.

> Veil is a data security add-on for
>   Postgres. It provides an API allowing
>   you to control access to data at the
>   row, or even column, level. Different
>   users will be able to run the same
>   query and see different results. Other
>   database vendors describe this as a
>   Virtual Private Database.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like it with views/rules of the data.  Also, 8.4 has column level permissions iirc.